# How to get a key from array of objects by its value Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections

I have a collection which looks like this:

```
    var array = [
     { 'key1': 'val1'},
     { 'key2': 'val2'}
    ];
```

I want a function which takes array and value as parameters and returns key of that value (values are unique)

```
 getKey(array, 'val1');
 >>>>> output: 'key1'
```

I tried the following solution but it says key property is not defined:

```
         getKey(array, value) {
            var keys = [];
            array.forEach(function(element) {
                for (key in element) {
                    if(value == element[key]) {
                        keys.push(key);
                    }
                }
            })

            return keys[0];
        },
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective is to help you fix your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{ 'key1': 'val1'}, { 'key2': 'val2'}];

function getKey(data,value) {
let keys=[];
data.forEach(function(element) {
  for (key in element) {
     if(element[key]==value)
       keys.push(key);
  }
});
return keys
}

console.log(getKey(arr, 'val1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an inverse object with `value` as `key` and `key` as `value`. And then finally access the `value` from object as key.

```js
var array = [{ 'key1': 'val1'},{ 'key2': 'val2'}];

function getKey(arr, val) {
  let obj = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
    Object.entries(c).forEach(([k,v]) => a[v]=k);
    return a;
  }, {})
  return obj[val];
}

console.log(getKey(array, 'val1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```js
var arr = [{ 'key1': 'val1'}, { 'key2': 'val2'}];

function getKey(arr, val) {
  var result = 'not found';
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    for (var key in obj) {
      if(obj[key] === val) result = key;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getKey(arr, 'val1'));
console.log(getKey(arr, 'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JS you can take all the entries, flatten them and simply search the value in all couples and if found then just take the first entry of that couple.

```
[].concat(...array.map(Object.entries)).find(a=>a[1]=='val1')[0]
```

Here is an working example:

```js
var array = [{'key1': 'val1'}, {'key2': 'val2'}, {'key3': 'val3'}],
    getKey = (arr,v)=>[].concat(...arr.map(Object.entries)).find(a=>a[1]==v)[0];
    
console.log(getKey(array, 'val2'));
console.log(getKey(array, 'val3'));
```

However, I will suggest you to use `lodash` (or `underscore`, or `lazy`) to make it more cleaner and simple.

Here is a **lodash** approach:

```
_.findKey(_.merge({}, ...array), s=>s=='val1')
```

Here is a woking example:

```js
var array = [{'key1': 'val1'}, {'key2': 'val2'}, {'key3': 'val3'}],
    getKey = (arr,v)=>_.findKey(_.merge({}, ...arr), s=>s==v);
    
console.log(getKey(array, 'val2'));
console.log(getKey(array, 'val3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```